# Unwanted result by locations calculations

Tags: java, android

In my application I generate a location every 5 minutes and send it to the db if it fits my standards.
One of the standards is that the new location that generated is not equal to the old one.
The following condition should cover it (and some other things) but in real time it doesn't.

```
if(newLocation != null)
{
  if(location != null)
  {
    if(location.getAccuracy() > newLocation.getAccuracy() + 100)
      sendTask();
    else
      if(newLocation.distanceTo(location) > 1800)
      sendTask();
  }
  else
    sendTask();
}
```

The send task method means, send to db. If the newLocation and the Location has the same coordinates the sendTask method shouldn't be exceuted and it is!

Why?

Comment: What is the purpose of the first sendTask() call?

Comment: To send the location to the db.

Comment: I was really trying to get an explanation of why that specific if condition on the accuracies is a reason for sending the location to the db.

Comment: If the new location has a better acuuracy then the old one that I wont to use it.

Comment: So the condition for using the new location is supposed to be about accuracy, not location?

Comment: The first condition is about the accuracy of the location yes, and the second one checks if I have moved enough to update my location. I'm not interesting in so many tiny location updates.